# Two-electron Integrals over Gaussian Plane Waves

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Is there an efficient method to compute the two-electron integrals over the basis set represented by a product of a Gaussian function $g(r)$ and plane wave:

$\psi(r)=g(r)e^{ikr}$

where $\lambda=1/k$ is approximately one fifth of the width of gaussians.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics mathematics.

Comment: where could i ask it?

Comment: You could try the Physics Stackexchange

Comment: you might be interested in helping us start a brand new stack exchange just for this type of question: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if anyone has done it, but the closest I can think of is the GPW (mixed Gaussian Plane Wave) method. I think that involves a mapping between Gaussian and PW basis. It's DFT, but just look for the Coulomb integrals.

General idea:

*Lippert, Gerald, et al. "A hybrid Gaussian and plane wave density functional scheme." Molecular Physics 92.3 (1997): 477-488.*

The implementation can be found here:

*VandeVondele, Joost, et al. "Quickstep: Fast and accurate density functional calculations using a mixed Gaussian and plane waves approach." Computer Physics Communications 167.2 (2005): 103-128.*